# Почему не выделяется текст в слайдах?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Как сделать, чтобы выделялся текст в слайдах и не было синего аутлайна при нажатии? [Пример здесь](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/XRVOyG)

Вот сам JS-код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider--preview-articles').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        dotsClass: "slider__dots slider__dots--centered",
        arrows: false,
        speed: 500,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        draggable: false,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1599,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 991,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Для выделения текста */
.slider--preview-articles {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
.slider--preview-articles.draggable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Убираем outline */
.slider--preview-articles .slider__slide {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)